# Inner html for a Master detail table

Tags: html

I am trying to create a master detail table where one of the rows will contain the detail of a child object.  For example we could have a customer and when you click on a row, it expands out to show the customer's orders.  The html might look something this:

```
<table id="report">
    <tr>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <!-- Details here -->  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What would be the best html/css for cross browser compatibility?  I need to support IE6.  I want to avoid putting an inner table inside.  If I use an unordered list, could I use css to get nice grid effect?

Comment: Seeing as you are already using a table, what is the reason you don't want to nest a table, it sounds like most logical way to solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ULs or DIVs to get a grid effect by placing each row in an LI tag, and filling that LI with floated block elements like DIVs that are the same width as your table columns.

```
<ul>
<li>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px">item1</div>
<div style="float; width: 120px;">item2</div>
...
</li>
...
```

But you would have to measure your floated DIVs exactly to the pixel, or they may wrap around and break the whole layout. Also if the container div ever gets resized it may break. You could apply a clear="both" to each LI to minimize breakage.

Be aware that if you use any margins on your floated divs that they will suffer from the double margin bug in ie6.

But this is not what UL is for. If you are trying to follow modern trends that shun using tables for anything, you should consider that this is exactly the type of tabular data that tables are supposed to display: Rows and columns of data. It would be semantically correct to use a table and I can't think of any advantage of not using one.

Not to mention that if ie6 compatibility is (unfortunately, shamefully) a big part of the specs of your project, then forget about being super modern and just use traditional working tables.

Ideally I would stop using colspan="4" and have your dynamic code assume that it will be nested inside a 4 column table, and just loop through table rows. As Jeremy B said in his comment, you already have a table anyway.

Comment: I take your point but the user's choice of browser is out of my hands and in the hands of the corporate IT nazis who simply will not upgrade their browsers.

Comment: But my point was exactly that. You should stop following internet trends that tell you to replace every table with a div or a list, because sometimes tables are both semantically correct and far easier to implement and maintain. I was not suggesting breaking compatability with ie6 to use divs. I was warning you not to do it.